# Folder view not being saved

Tags: windows-7, user-folders

Windows 7 x64. Past few days Windows stopped remembering folder view settings. I've been trying solutions for 10 hours now, nothing helped (don't want to restore windows).

I've recreated all Bag and BagMRU keys. Set to 20,000. Tried changing library settings, Folder settings, I think I've tried it all. It just keeps going back to list view, sort by name. Even when I optimize a folder to a different type - say "images", it will just go back to "General items". I've used software like shellbagview and shellbag_analyzer_cleaner and they show "0" bags - so nothing is being saved in reg. I have full permissions in reg. I changed all kinds of keys and also reset them - nothing worked.

Also folder SIZE doesn't save as it used to for YEARS. When I rescale a folder and close it and then re-open - it goes back to small, tiny size.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to fix user profile. It might be corrupted. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/14039/windows-7-fix-corrupted-user-profile

Comment: Good idea for starters. So created new user, the ONLY thing behaving correctly in new user account was window SIZE. Scaled the explorer window and closed it, it REMEMBERED the size when reopening. Great. But it still has the issue of going back to "general items" when trying to change a specific folder view to say, pictures. Also, I copied ALL "bags" reg values from new user (that had window x.y. positions saved in bags keys) to MY admin account but I still have BOTH issues in my account. Since at least ONE thing is working in new account (resize) - how to get that copied to MY account...